# jquery and a href 's text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following a href

```
<a href="javascript:cs();">Alberta</a>
```

And I want to access the text of a href that is Alberta

My javascript/jquery code is following

```
  function cs() {

    $(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            alert($(this).html());

        });
    });


    setCookie("province", $(this).closest("a").text())
    alert("");
}
```

I have tried .text and .val but with no luck.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: you need to call "attr". $(this).attr('href')

Comment: alert($(this).attr('href'));

Comment: IIRC, you'll need to pass `this` as an argument. Then you can access it without the need of `closest`

Comment: There seems to be an error in the question, you say you want to get href of the a element but the href will be "javascript:cs;". If you want to get the text of the a link, try $(..).text();

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting something like this

```
<a onclick="getValues(this)" href="javascript:return false;">Alberta</a>

function getValues(hrefEle)
{
  alert("inner text = "+$(hrefEle).text());
  alert("href = "+$(hrefEle).attr("href"));
}
```

Comment: it's giving undefined

Comment: No it works perfectly for me. Double check whether you pass "this" param for getValues function i.e onclick="getValues(this)"

Comment: I don't want to use onclick I am using a href and inserting javascript into a href=javascript:cs()

Comment: Yap but it is not recommended! You should not use href for JavaScript. Bad practice, instead use onclick. And return false or prevent default for href. Can't you do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply do like this also

```
<a href="javascript:cs();" id="test">Alberta</a>
<script>
function cs() {
            alert($("#test").html());
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want!!

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">Alberta</a>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on("click", function(){
        alert($("a").text());
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g8fdhxz1/)